# EntityFramework 6.1.3, entity added, Context.SaveChanges does not insert, no errors

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using the latest EF 6 version connecting to an SQL Server 2012 database. Everything has been working smoothly for months in a live deployment, but I recently added a feature where I'm calling SaveChanges() twice on the same context after adding two new entities.

I add an entity of type T to my context after model validation, then invoke SaveChanges() which succeeds without errors or validation problems. This entity is correctly inserted.

Using the same context, I then proceed to create a fresh instance of type T by copying over some of the values from the original (mostly primitive types, but a few references too). This too validates fully and SaveChanges() does not raise any errors, but maybe 50% of the time, the ID is still 0 and no SQL output is logged, so the entity is not inserted.

If I call Context.Entry(entity), it says the status is Added, and Context.ChangeTracker.Entries returns this new entity in the list of changes.

I created a test loop that continuously calls SaveChanges while the entity ID is 0, and it loops forever with no errors.

I'm stumped. Anyone have any bright ideas what I can try now?

Edit: to prove this is a legit issue, I changed the save code so that the second save happens on a brand new context, where I reload all the entities referenced by the second entity I want to insert. The insert succeeds every time. So code went from this *broken code* running on a single context:

```
// insert 'item' if model is valid, should only attempt second insert if first save is successful
if (ModelState.IsValid && this.SaveIsValid(item))
{
    var next = item.NextRun(); // create a new run from existing run, copying some data
    // save entity to db (insert or update)
    this.SaveIsValid(next); // returns true=no errors, but entity NOT inserted
}
```

to this *working code* that uses *two* contexts:

```
// insert 'item' if model is valid, should only attempt second insert if first save is successful
if (ModelState.IsValid && this.SaveIsValid(item))
{
    // ugly hack workaround because saving twice on the same context sometimes fails
    var saved = db;
    db = new Models.SanDbContext();
    try
    {
        // create a new run in Running status, and redirect to edit it
        var next = item.NextRun();
        next.Machine = db.Machines.Find(next.Machine.Id);
        next.Operator = db.Users.Find(next.Operator.Id);
        next.PartCode = db.PartCodes.Find(next.PartCode.Id);
        foreach (var m in next.Measurements)
            m.InputType = db.MeasurementTypes.Find(m.InputType.Id);
        foreach (var c in next.Coils)
            c.Coil = db.SanCoils.Find(c.Coil.Id);
        this.SaveIsValid(next);  // returns true=no errors, entity inserted
    }
    finally
    {
        db.Dispose();
        db = saved;
    }
}
```

There should be no functional difference between the two that I can see, but one works every time, the other fails about half of the time.

Edit 2: per a suggestion in the comments, I'd like to clarify that I do NOT make use of any no tracking queries, so all entities are tracked.

Comment: Its hard for us to help without seeing the code that's causing the issue.  Add your code to the question.

Comment: It's just regular Context.EntityType.Add(entity), Context.SaveChanges() and it's been working fine for single entity saves for months. The same code is used for both saves (encapsulated in a function), so it's not going to illuminate anything. I'm asking for suggestions on what to try next to figure out what EF might be doing or why it's failing.

Comment: have you give primary key in table?

Comment: Yes, a standard IDENTITY column. Like I said, saving works fine and has been for months on a live deployment, it's just saving the second entity in a row on the same context that fails with no errors about half the time.

Comment: Your context potentially could be needed to be refreshed as it accepted changes but in it's own context(ha) it doesn't know what happened.  Since you give no code it is just guesses at this point.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion djangojazz, but refreshing only seems relevant if I'm updating entities. There's nothing to refresh when I'm inserting a brand new entity. Calling Context.Entry(entity).Reload() throws InvalidOperationException when the entity is being inserted. Unless you're referring to something else?

Comment: I've just added some code to demonstrate a workaround by saving on a brand new context. This should be functionally equivalent, but works every time where the original code fails half the time. I look forward to hearing your suggestions for why this might be!

Comment: It's unclear from your limited code you show, but it appears you're mixing entities from two different instances of EF.  The "item" comes from somewhere, but you new up a "db" context and assign entities retrieved from the context that retrieved "item".  This doesn't work, entities must be from the same context.

Comment: Erik, the code that uses the same context everywhere *doesn't work*. The workaround I posted using a second context *does work*, and I explained that I explicitly reload the entities in the second context to make sure there are no problems.

Comment: @naasking - well, what exactly does NextRun() do?  it would help to see that.  Also, what exactly does "SaveIfValid" do?  Saying "it just does blah" doesn't help because all too often people think something isn't an issue and can be omitted when it's actually the cause of the problem.

Comment: @naasking - The fact that it works when you get new instances of the related entities points to the "but one or two references" being the issue.  WHICH references?  Do you mean references to related entities?  Are those entities retrieved as Not Tracked entities?  Seeing the code would answer a lot of questions.  Also, you're being downvoted mostly because you refuse to show your actual code, but still asking us to debug your code psychically.

Comment: I'm not refusing to show code, the code simply will not answer your questions Erik. Going through 500 lines of code is a waste of both of our time. I'm not asking you to debug my code, I asked for suggestions to try and figure out what EF might be doing so *I* can debug the code. The second code snippet enumerates precisely all of the FK entities in the entity being inserted. I've updated the post with a little more context. If the problem were with the related entities, the first insert would also fail, but never does. I will be happy to run any test you suggest if you still think it's there.

Comment: this.SaveIsValid checks the page's model state, calls db.Set<T>().Add(entity) if needed, then just calls db.SaveChanges() and logs any errors or other unexpected problems. Like I said, it's boring code that's used in every page in the whole program and it's been working for months, the problem is not here.

Comment: Oh, and NextRun() just calls "new Entity { Machine = item.Machine, Operator = item.Operator, ... }", etc. Also very boring code, nothing special here. Just setting properties on a new entity. All collection entities are recreated from scratch, again copying over data so there's no sharing between both entities. Saving on a second context wouldn't work if there was any sharing, I'd get an untracked entity error if that were the case.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I do not perform any no tracking queries in the entire program Erik, so it's definitely not that. Good thought though, that's exactly the kind of suggestion I'm looking for.